# Find if HTML data attribute exists in any ancestor elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have reference to an element, `baseElement`, and I want to find if some HTML data attribute exists somewhere on one of its ancestors, and to get the value of it if it is found. If the attribute exists on multiple ancestors, I just want the attribute on the one that is most closely related.

I've designed a loop that goes up by parents and checks if the attribute exists. Assume the first parent of `baseElement` is not null.

```
let currentElement = baseElement.parentElement;
let foundAttribute = false;
let valueOfAttribute = null;

do {
  foundAttribute = currentElement.hasAttribute('html-attribute');
  if (foundAttribute) {
    valueOfAttribute = currentElement.getAttribute('html-attribute');
  } else {
    currentElement = currentElement.parentElement;
  }
} while (!foundAttribute && currentElement);
```

I want to see if there is a more efficient, more eloquent, or easier-to-code way of doing this. Please, only pure JavaScript answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to see if there is a more efficient, more eloquent, or easier-to-code way of doing this.

There certainly is. Meet [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```
let ancestor = baseElement.closest('[html-attribute]');
let attr_val = ancestor ? ancestor.getAttribute('html-attribute') : null;
```

`closest()` takes a selector, just like `querySelector` and similar methods.

Comment: Oh yay. Thanks for introducing me.